# Link to Google Play doesn't work Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I'm linking from my app to another app in Google Play.  The link works fine on my Nexus tablet and my ICS HTC One X, but the link gets an error on an HTC Inspire 4G Android 2.2, it says

> "The requested item could not be found."

This is the link I'm using:

```
String pushUrl = "market://details?id=com.laughingplaceapps.relaxopen";
```

And the code I'm using:

```
            Uri marketUri = Uri.parse(pushUrl);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is the other app available on android 2.2?

Comment: Yes it is available for 2.2.

Comment: try like this `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.laughingplaceapps.relaxopen` If that doesn't work either then unfortunately you have one of the rare devices that doesn't react correctly to market URLs ( I've seen an HTC device that will only open them in the browser and not the market app.)

Answer (score 1):

If Google Play App (Market) is not available on the phone, the implicit intent `market://` will not run. You can use `PackageManager.getInstalledPackages()` to check if there is an App to handle your implicit intent. And if not you can use change your `URI` to a URL linking to the App via web browser (`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.laughingplaceapps.relaxopen`) as stated in the comments above, which will cause the implicit intent to be handled by the browser instead.

Comment: Good point, but I think the phone does have Google Play App.  I will check with him though and verify.  Thanks for the tip!